# Pandas- Cumilative Sum of previous row values

Tags: python, pandas

Here is sample dataset:

```
   id   a
0   5   1
1   5   0
2   5   4
3   5   6
4   5   2
5   5   3
6   9   0
7   9   1
8   9   6
9   9   2
10  9   4
```

From the dataset, I want to generate a column `sum`. For first 3 rows: `sum`=`sum`+`a`(group by id). From 4th row, each row contains the cumulative sum of the previous 3 rows of `a` value(group by id). Loop through each row.

Desired Output:

```
   id   a sum
0   5   1   1
1   5   0   1
2   5   4   5
3   5   6   5
4   5   2   10
5   5   3   12
6   9   0   0
7   9   1   1
8   9   6   7
9   9   2   7
10  9   4   9
```

Code I tried:

```
df['sum']=df['a'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=3).groupby(df['id']).cumsum()
```

Comment: so you always want the fourth row to be the same as the third row, within each ID?

Comment: Yeah. After fourth row each row contains the cumulative sum of the previous 3 rows of `a` column(group by id).

Comment: huh. that's definitely not a standard operation like cumsum. try grouping first, and then write your own custom function to do this operation, e.g. `df.groupby('id').apply(custom_cumulative_sum_function)` which does what you'd like within each ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a functiona like the below:

```
def cumsum_last3(DF):
    nrow=DF.shape[0]
    DF["sum"]=0
    DF["sum"].iloc[0]=DF["a"].iloc[0]
    DF["sum"].iloc[1]=DF["a"].iloc[0]+DF["a"].iloc[1]
    for a in range(nrow-2):
        cums=np.sum(DF["a"].iloc[a:a+3])
        DF["sum"].iloc[a+2]=cums
    return DF

DF_cums=cumsum_last3(DF)
DF_cums
```

[image]

Comment: It just only sums the last 3 rows. How do I group it by `id`? When a new `id` appears it should calculate from begining.

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to understand what you are trying to do. can you provide an example?