# Pandas- Create column based on sum of previous row values

Tags: pandas

Sample dataset:

```
   id val
0   9   1
1   9   0
2   9   4
3   9   6
4   9   2
5   9   3
6   5   0
7   5   1
8   5   6
9   5   2
10  5   4
```

From the dataset, I want to generate a column `sum`. For the first 3 rows: `sum`=`sum`+`val`(group by id). From 4th row, each row contains the cumulative sum of the previous 3 rows of `val` column(group by id). Loop through each row. When a new id appears, it should calculate from the beginning.

Desired Output:

```
    id  val sum
0    9    1   1
1    9    0   1
2    9    4   5
3    9    6  10
4    9    2  12
5    9    3  11
6    5    0   0
7    5    1   1
8    5    6   7
9    5    2   9
10   5    4  12
```

Code I tried:

```
df['sum']=df['val'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=3).groupby(df['id']).cumsum()
```

How do I figure out the custom cumulative sum function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas- Cumilative Sum of previous row values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68748802/pandas-cumilative-sum-of-previous-row-values)(duplicate)

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the expected output is correct?

I would do:

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby('id')['val'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=3).sum().values
```

output:

```
    id  val   sum
0    5    1   1.0
1    5    0   1.0
2    5    4   5.0
3    5    6  10.0
4    5    2  12.0
5    5    3  11.0
6    9    0   0.0
7    9    1   1.0
8    9    6   7.0
9    9    2   9.0
10   9    4  12.0
```

Comment: If you really want the given output, you can use `shift` to move the rows.

Comment: alright. but I want int datatype in sum column. how do I do that?

Comment: Use `(...).sum().astype(int).values` in place of `(...).sum().values`

Comment: I have faced a problem. When I change id value 5 in place of 9 and 9 in place of 5, it should give me exact same output as before. But your solution gives me wired result. Can you please check? I have edited my dataset.

Comment: I imagine you want to add `sort=False` as a parameter to `groupby`